# VueJS simple togooling with radio buttons

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My requirement is something like this.

I have two radio buttons namely **Live Paper** and **Normal Paper**

If user select Live Paper another two html `input elements`(`datatime-local`,`time`) must be shown.

If the user selected the Normal Paper these two additional input elements should be hide.
How do I achieve this through vueJS.

This is my code.

```js
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="radio" name="paper" value="">Live Papaer
      <br>
      Live on <input type="datetime-local" name="" value="" > Time <input type="time" name="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="radio" name="paper" value="">Normal Paper
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just initialize a property named `selected` in your data option

```
new Vue({
   el:"#app",
   data(){
       return{
           selected: 'live'
       }
   }
 })
```

Bind this `selected` property to both the radio inputs. See that the `value` attribute of radio inputs is set to `live` and `normal` respectively

Set up `v-if` on the div you conditionally want to render. The `v-if` is only true when `selected === 'live'`

```
<div id="app">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="radio" name="paper" v-model="selected" value="live">Live Papaer
          <div v-if="selected === 'live'">
              Live on <input type="datetime-local" name="" value="" > Time <input type="time" name="" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="radio" name="paper" v-model="selected" value="normal">Normal Paper
        </div>
   </div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4tafyhk/3/)
Reference:  [radio inputs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look to these documentations :

- [VueJS Forms : Basics](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage)
- [Vue JS Forms : Radio buttons](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio)
- [Vue JS Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Also, from the community, you can find a lot of resources to understand View Binding and Forms in VueJS :

- [Understand what's behind v-model](https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/)
- [2-Way Binding in Vue with V-Model - Vue.js 2.0 Fundamentals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEdsu6heW9o)